# Why a SqlParameter does not get value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sqlparameter

I am trying to initialize the value of a `SqlParameter` with a string. but why does it not get the value ?

This is what I tried:

```
 int loadChart(string status)
 {
        connect();

        SqlParameter[] parameters ={
                                      new SqlParameter("status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10),
                                      new SqlParameter("count", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
                                  };

        parameters[0].Value = status;
        parameters[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Arsenic_getSourceStatusCount", objConnection);

        foreach (SqlParameter param in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        disConnect();

        int count;
        count =(int) parameters[1].Value;

        return count;
    }
}
```

The stored procedure:

```
alter procedure sp_Arsenic_getSourceStatusCount
@status varchar(10),
@count int
as
select @count=COUNT(status) from Arsenic_WaterSource where status=@status
return 1
```

Inserting a breakpoint I have discovered that the string variable `status` gets its value "safe" but at `parameters[0].Value = (string) status;` line `parameters[0].value` gets `null`. How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: why are you typecasting a string to a string ?

Comment: for no reason..its double checking

Comment: What are you passing as Status?  I used the string "Test" and it set the value.

Comment: try removing that.. i dont see anything weird apart from that

Comment: I am passing "safe" as status value and yes its length is <=10

Comment: Seems to work for me - are you not getting it in the stored proc?  Maybe an @ sign before the variable name?

Comment: @Decker97 see my edited version

Comment: I wonder if OP's problem was ever solved.

Answer (score 3):

You did not define your @count parameter as an OUTPUT parameter in your procedure:

```
alter procedure sp_Arsenic_getSourceStatusCount
@status varchar(10),
@count int OUTPUT  /* <--------------  */
as
select @count=COUNT(status) from Arsenic_WaterSource where status=@status
return 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
connect();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Arsenic_getSourceStatusCount", objConnection);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", status));
SqlParameter pCount = new SqlParameter("@count", 0);
pCount.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(pCount);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

disConnect();

int count = Convert.ToInt32(parameters[1].Value);

return count;
```

And this:

```
alter procedure sp_Arsenic_getSourceStatusCount
@status varchar(10),
@count int = 0 OUTPUT
as
set nocount on
select @count=COUNT(status) from Arsenic_WaterSource where status=@status
go
```

Comment: I updated it. You need to either set a value for the output parameter or define it with a default value in the sproc.